# How to translate a Solr query into Elasticsearch

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to express this Solr (Lucene) query in Elastic Search, but I'm not sure how:

```
q=field1:"value1"^10 OR field2:("value2a"^20 OR "value2b"^30)
group=true
group.field=fieldGroup
```

Is there a way to simply pass a Lucene query to ES, so I don't need to first translate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible to pass a Lucene query into Elasticsearch using a [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query. Something like this should be plausible:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "field1:\"value1\"^10 OR field2:(\"value2a\"^20 OR \"value2b\"^30)"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use aggregations to mimic your field collapsing: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html

Comment: extra question: in my actual use case, one field has a space in it (i.e. it's not "field1", it's "field 1". The query "field 1:\"value1\"" (treating the space in the field name as a normal character) is executed but gives incorrect/unexpected results, and the query "\"field 1\":\"value1\"" (surrounding the field name with double quotes) returns an error. Any idea about this one?